# How do I stop VSCode from starting up maximized?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On just one of my two Linux systems, Visual Studio Code always starts in a maximized window. It doesn't do it on the other one. Both systems are Pop!_OS 20.10, upgraded along the way from each Pop!_OS release from 18.04. VSCode is 1.51.1, and has been doing this since I started using it about 1.36 or so. I'm using the default Gnome Shell on each system. On the system where it doesn't start maximized, it remembers its previous size and placement. If I double-click on the window header on the failing system, it returns to its prior placement and size, but if I close it in that state, when I reopen it it's maximized again.

I'm guessing there's a settings file or something that's set to force it to be maximized, but I didn't explicitly set anything like that, and I wasn't able to find anything when searching that would have that effect.

The failing system is one I built up with a Ryzen 9 3900X, 64 GB RAM, 1 TB M.2 PCIe 4 SSD, and an RTX 2060. The working system is a System76 Oryx Pro v4 with 64 GB and an 8th gen Core i7. VSCode has done this on the failing system ever since I was running it on a dual-hex Mac Pro, and on a 1080p monitor; I'm now using a 3840x2160 monitor - but that's what the Oryx Pro has on it, too.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Following works on ubuntu 20.10. Position VSCode window where you would like it to open next time. Then, hit `<Ctrl><CloseXButton>`

This will close your current session. Next time you open this project via `code .`, you should get VSCode to open in that last state you `<Ctrl>`-closed it in.

I don't know where this status is stored in the settings file.

Comment: Good thought! But didn't work, sadly...just checking, by `<Ctrl><CloseXButton>`, you mean hold down the control key and click on the rounded X button in the top right corner of the window, right? (Yeah, that's basic, but I'm covering **all** the bases here.)

Comment: Yes, holding the control button down, use the mouse to close the windows by clicking on the X of the application window.

Comment: That's what I thought. It didn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: Tough luck. If you want a keyboard shortcut to resize windows of any application, (not exactly what you want, but it will avoid need of a mouse touch) atleast on Ubuntu 20.10 it is <power key>Uparrow for maximize, down arrow for minimize, left arrow for left half and right arrow for right half of window.